# Class model for html backend

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to web and I do not know if I'm doing this wrong. So I have a button like so :

```
<button id="login_btn" onclick="login()">Login</button>
```

and my index.js like so :

```
function login() {
    var user = document.getElementById("email_field").value;
    var pass = document.getElementById("pass_field").value;
    var loginPane = document.getElementById("login_page");
    var dashboardPane = document.getElementById("dashboard_page");

    dashboardPane.style.display = "block";
    loginPane.style.display = "none";
}
```

Now this works. But what If I want to access the loginPane variable inside another function. Meaning I have to move the loginPane variable outside this function like so :

```
var user = document.getElementById("email_field").value;
var pass = document.getElementById("pass_field").value;
var loginPane = document.getElementById("login_page");
var dashboardPane = document.getElementById("dashboard_page");

function login() {
    dashboardPane.style.display = "block";
    loginPane.style.display = "none";
}
```

Now I am getting the following error : `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null`

In Java you enclose everything in a class. How do I do it with this one? I am an Android developer and not a web app developer and so I do not know.

Comment: It is possible that HTML elements representing `dashboard_page` or `login_page`, haven't yet be created at the moment when you declare them.
When do you call the login function?

Comment: Just move `var dashboardPane;`. Leave assignment inside function. Also make sure you execute you JS after your HTML is loaded

Comment: First of all, this is totally insecure. Using display property to toggle dashboard and login form is totally insecure. Second, to answer your question, you should move the script from head to end of body tag. This happens because the script executes before the dom elements get loaded.

Comment: How do you suggest I toggle between panes then?

Comment: Moving the script to the end of the body tag works